# array with sessions, only prints one letter

Tags: php, arrays

On login:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username`, `email` FROM `users`
                   WHERE `username` = '$username'
        AND `password` = '$passwd'");
$userdata = array('id','username','email');
$_SESSION['user'] = mysql_result($result, 0, $userdata);
```

And when I want to print the users username:

```
echo $_SESSION['user']['username']
```

it only prints the first letter :/

What's wrong?

Comment: @jolabero:  welcome to SO. You can usually get more rapid help with your questions by tagging them with the language you are using.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Debug your variables at each stage by using var_dump() to determine where the problem lies. Also, using mysql_result in that fashion is needless, I'd recommend using [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) as it will do the same thing with less effort.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$_SESSION['user']['id'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'id');
$_SESSION['user']['username'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'username');
$_SESSION['user']['email'] = mysql_result($result, 0, 'email');
```

also make sure the database itself doesn't contain only first letter initially.

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably want to be using [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) instead of [mysql_result()](http://php.net/mysql_result).  `mysql_result()` only gives you a single cell value from your result set, so when you assign `$_SESSION['user'] = mysql_result($result,0,$userdata);`, you are only getting the first cell value of the result row.  Accessing it by an associative key (ie. `$_SESSION['user']['username']`) isn't possible, since it's not an array.

If you use `mysql_fetch_assoc()`, you'll have a key/value pair of your column names and values to work with:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT `id`, `username`, `email` FROM `users`
                   WHERE `username` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($username)."'
        AND `password` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($passwd)."'");
$_SESSION['user'] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

As a side benefit, `mysql_fetch_assoc()` is much faster than `mysql_result()`.

*Note:* I also put a [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) in there, as you must be sure to escape your query data somehow, unless you are sure it's safe.